# How can i set the page size that would not be changeable

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, electron

I am working on an electron app recently

My problem is that I don't want users to be able to change the page size

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean window size of your electron application you can set `minHeight`,  `minWidth` and `maxHeight`, `maxWidth` of your window

```
new BrowserWindow({
  width: 300, 
  height: 400, 
  minWidth: 300, 
  minHeight: 400,
  maxHeight: 300, 
  maxWidth: 400
});
```

or alternative way is to set `resizable` to `false`, which by default is `true`

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the proper way is to use the `resizable` and `fullscreenable` properties set to `false`:

```
new BrowserWindow({
  width: 300, 
  height: 400, 
  resizable: false, 
  fullscreenable: false
});
```